Kafka message with same key to be distributed equally among 2 partitions
I want to distribute kafka messages with the same key equally among 2 partitions. I have
the following code.
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner;
import org.apache.kafka.common.Cluster;

public class MessageBalancePartitioner implements Partitioner{
    
    private  int partition=0;
    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
        
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       
    }

    @Override
    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes,Object value, byte[]  valueInBytes, Cluster cluster) {
      
      
        if(partition==0) {
            partition=1;
      
        }
        else {
            partition=0;
      
        }
        return partition;
        
    }

}


Sender code
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;




public class SenderWithMessageBalancePartitioner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props=new Properties();
    //kafka server url
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, MessageBalancePartitioner.class.getName());
    
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer=new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    String topic="x-topic";
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
        
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record=new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                "first-key","This is test message "+i
                );
      
        producer.send(record,new Callback() {
            
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata rmd, Exception ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(ex==null) {
                    System.out.println("message published at partition: "+rmd.partition());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    
    producer.close();
    
    System.out.println("messages sent");
}
}


It is not working as expected. It publishes the message always to partition 0.
x-topic has been created with 2 partions.
What is the problem with this? Thank you.
The custom partitioner is not honoured by the message sender.

You can set the partition in the ProducerRecord... I'm not sure partitioner classes are allowed to maintain stateful variables. Have you tried using a debugger, though?
